# WinForms RichTextBox issue

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have the following code to format lines being added to a RichTextBox control:

```
rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 14, FontStyle.Bold);
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.SteelBlue;
rtb.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
rtb.AppendText("This is the message to display");
rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

rtb.SelectionFont = new Font(new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif"), 10, FontStyle.Regular);
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
rtb.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
rtb.AppendText("This is the log message");
```

It producese the following RTF string:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang4105{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Microsoft
>   Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} {\colortbl
>   ;\red70\green130\blue180;\red0\green0\blue0;}
>   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\b\f0\fs28 This is the message to
>   display\cf2\b0\fs20\par This is the log message\cf0\f1\fs17\par }

If I save that string with the RTF extension and open the document in WordPad i get the expected result, however in the application the formats are not being applied.

Is there a setting in the control I'm missing?

Thank you,

> **UPDATE: Modified the code as suggested by LarsTech.  Now the alignment
>   works but the font formatting still does not.**
>
> **UPDATE: The reason was the location where the code was being run.  The user control containing the rich text box has an Initialize
>   function that is called before the Load event.  This was preventing
>   the formatting from being applied.  Once I saved the RTF string to a
>   local variable and used it in the Load event handler the formatting
>   works correctly. Marked LarstTech as the answer barbecue his comment
>   did fix the alignment issue. Thank you All.**

Comment: How are you saving it and how are you loading it?

Comment: I stop the debugger and take the current text of the Rtf property of the control.  Using Notepad++ I remove the extra '\' used in the c# string for escaping and replace '\r\n' with the enter key.  Then I save the file with the RTF extension.

Comment: Well, don't do that.  Just use the rtf property to get and set your information.

Comment: I did that to see if the Rtf property was being build properly using the code above, which it seems to be.  What I do not understand is why does the actual rtb control does not display text formatted as coded.

Comment: You doubted the RTF control would properly create an rtf string?  Your post talks about WordPad, your comment talks about the debugger.  You are making the question hard to answer because we can't see what the problem is you are having.  Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: Tried the code above and the RTB shows correctly the font size and color, not the center alignement.

Comment: It's the code above. The string "This is the message to display" should show centered in size 14 and SteelBlue colour. The string "\r\nThis is the log message" should show in the next line left-aligned in size 10 and black. This is not happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a line break:

```
rtb.AppendText("This is the message to display");
rtb.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

and remove your manual line break:

```
//rtb.AppendText("\r\nThis is the log message");
rtb.AppendText("This is the log message");
```

The SelectionAlignment needs to be applied *after* the line break is set.  In your code, the line break is happening too late.

Comment: Thank you.  This made the alignment work, however the font size and weight are still not being applied.  I tried it with a new project and it works.  I will try to find why it does not work on this particular project.

Comment: @Fernando Your comment to Steve says Font Size 14, but your code says Font Size 10, and *not* bold.

Comment: The first message is Size 14, Bold, SteelBlue and Centered.

Comment: @Fernando Yes, it is.  The second line is size 10, black, and left.  We aren't looking at the same thing.

Comment: @Fernando The code you just updated on your question works.  The first line is centered, blue, size 14 and bold, the second line is left, black and size 10.  The font formatting is working.

Comment: Thanks.  I did do it on a new project and you are correct it works.  However on this existing project id does not.  I'll try to figure out why.  Both target the same Framework Version, so I really do not understand unless is some of the parent controls formatting this one ???

Answer (score 0):

```
rtb.Rtf = //Your rtf string
```

Alternatively, you can use `LoadFile` if you are actually loading an `RTF file`

```
public void LoadMyFile()
{
   // Create an OpenFileDialog to request a file to open.
   OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

   // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to look for RTF files.
   openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
   openFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

   // Determine whether the user selected a file from the OpenFileDialog. 
   if(openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
      openFile1.FileName.Length > 0) 
   {
      // Load the contents of the file into the RichTextBox.
      richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName);
   }
}
```

Comment: rtb.Rtf = RTFString was my first pass and it still did not work.  I'm building the text form application data, therefore loading from the file is not an option.  Thank you.

Comment: I just get it from the rtb.Rtf property by stopping the debugger.

Comment: Don't do that. That would invalidate your `RTF` unless you use the correct `debug visualizer` so that the string is not corrupted. Keep in mind C# uses `UTF-16`

Comment: I only did it to check that it was building the string.  What I need to know is why the formats are not applied using my code.  The string that results from that code after I remove the escaping and \r\n literals work fine in WordPad.

Answer (score 0):

Saving and loading RTF file, below code must work, or open the RTF file manually use the @lll answer **LoadMyFile()** method.

```
        //Save to rtf file
        rtb.SaveFile("e:\\aaaa.rtf");
        //or
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText( "e:\\aaaa.rtf",rtb.Rtf,System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII);//without BOM signature.
        // end of save to rtf


        //Load from rtf file.
        rtb.LoadFile("e:\\aaaa.rtf");
        //or
        rtb.Rtf = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("e:\\aaaa.rtf", System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII); 
        //end of load rtf from file
```